# Biblatex / Biber with babel ngerman - sentence case not working

Tags: biblatex, biber, babel, apa-style

When I use `biblatex` with `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` sentence casing in the references stop working. When I deactivate `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` it works well. See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,style=apa,isbn=false,doi=false,eprint=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @article{Bandura.1999,
        author = {Bandura, Albert},
        year = {1999},
        title = {Moral Disengagement in the Perpetration of Inhumanities},
        pages = {193--209},
        volume = {3},
        number = {3},
        issn = {1088-8683},
        journal = {Personality and Social Psychology Review},
        doi = {10.1207/s15327957pspr0303{\textunderscore }3}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
    \citep{Bandura.1999}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How can I combine both (sentence casing for english sources and using `ngerman`), since the thesis is written in German, but has a lot of English sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not explicitly give the language of the entry in the `.bib` file via the `langid` field, `biblatex` will automatically use the rules of the surrounding language. In your case that means that `biblatex` will not apply sentence casing since sentence casing is not enabled for German (as ordered with `ngerman`) by default (and it would not make sense to enable it).

The solution is to add `langid = {english},` to English works. On the other hand you will also want to add `langid = {ngerman},` to the German works you cite in case you want to use them in an English document to avoid sentence casing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bandura.1999,
  author  = {Bandura, Albert},
  year    = {1999},
  title   = {Moral Disengagement in the Perpetration of Inhumanities},
  pages   = {193--209},
  volume  = {3},
  number  = {3},
  issn    = {1088-8683},
  journal = {Personality and Social Psychology Review},
  doi     = {10.1207/s15327957pspr0303_3},
  langid  = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \autocite{Bandura.1999}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bandura, A. (1999). Moral disengagement in the perpetration of inhumanities. Personality and Social Psychology Review, 3(3), 193–209. https://doi.org/10.1207/s15327957pspr0303_3]